# Can I use multiple IP address on my EC2 instance using RDP?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rdp

I have 1 AWS - EC2 instance (windows server 2008 r2) running - I configured the security group to my IP address - I downloaded the RDP for it, and was able to logged in successfully,and now I want to give my friend's computer an access to the EC2 instance I have.

how do you I add another ip address on an EC2 instance so that my team can access the same windows server on AWS?

we want to use the server as a development environment. please advice. 
thanks in advance.

Comment: Just add another rule to the security group providing access to the port RDP uses.

Comment: @datasage, thank u for your reply, so i'll just add another inbound rule on the security group and input the IP address of my teammate, right?, but how about, if his IP address is dynamic, is this solution still apply?

Comment: It will, but you would have to change it each time his IP changed. Having a static IP is better for situations like this. If its dynamic within a small block of IP addresses, you can open access to the entire block.